# In Jenkins pipeline, what is the correct way to perform mutual-authentication REST requests?

Tags: rest, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, mutual-authentication

I am calling a REST service from a Jenkins Pipeline. This REST service uses mutual authentication so I must provide a client certificate to authenticate.

I could store the certificate with my Jenkinsfile in Git - could I then pass this cert to the REST call?

This is performed in cURL with the --cert param:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" \
--cert ens.p12 \
https://hostname:9000/api/bakery -k
```

How do we get it so that the cert will be used in the Groovy request?

```
def get = new URL("https://hostname:9000/api/bakery").openConnection();
get.setRequestMethod("GET")
get.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
get.getInputStream().getText()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using cURL with `sh` provided by the Jenkins Pipeline DSL as this seems to handle the requirement in the most succinct way.

```
JSON = sh (
  script: 'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cert ens.p12 https://hostname:9000/api/bakery -k',
  returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy you should be using [HttpBuilder](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/).

The code could look like:

```
def request = ApacheHttpBuilder.configure{
  request.uri = 'https://hostname:9000/api/bakery'
  request.contentType = 'application/json'
  client.clientCustomizer{ HttpClientBuilder builder ->
    builder.sSLContext = provideYourSSLContext()
  }
}.get{
  response.success{ resp, json ->
    println "$resp.statusCode / got JSON: $json"
  }
}
```

Here you have to load your cert in `provideYourSSLContext()` method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using an external dependency?

Comment: you can set up `SSLContext` for your HttpUrlConnection - for the code you shown in your post. Another option, provided you use gradle in your pipeline, you can use Httpbuilder gradle plugin